# How can i use redefineClasses() method in javaagents

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I have been using `premain()` with `addTransformer()`. Since, it gives `javassist.ClassNotFound` exceptions for certain classes when i run the agent with a server, i thought to try the `agentMain()` with `redefineClasses()`. I went through many links, but so far i am unable to find a piece of code that gives me clear idea on how to set up a simple java agent using these two methods. Some help would be really appreciated.

Can we use `redefineClasses()` with `premain()`? (When we use `redefineClasses()` do we still need the `transform` method?)

I am trying to instrument set of methods of set of classes, where i know the fully qualified name of those classes as `com.test.Foo`. I wanted to instrument them without going through the entire set of classes loaded onto JVM. I have been reading those documents back and forth, but still i am unable to get a clear idea on how to use that `redefineClasses` method?

Comment: You should tell, what you are trying to achieve and why the documentation found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses-java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...-) is insufficient.

Comment: Well those documentations explains the method, but there is no clear example on how to use it. I mean like a simple end to end example.

Comment: I came across a few articles with actual examples. http://www.fasterj.com/articles/hotpatch1.shtml and http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2008/09/java-instrumentation-with-jdk-16x-class.html

Answer (score 2):

You can call `redefineClasses` from anywhere, also from a `premain` method which is nothing but an extension to a normal Java program run by the same JVM process previous to a `main` method.

A trivial example for running a redefinition is:

```
instrumentation.redefineClasses(new ClassDefinition(Foo.class, new byte[] {...}));
```

This way, `Foo` is set to be represented by the byte array that **must** contain a valid class file for `Foo` where all signatures of fields and methods are the same as by the loaded `Foo.class`. You can use a tool like ASM for instrumenting the class.

If you really only want to instrument `Foo`, then this might just be the way to go instead of using a `ClassFileTransformer`.